# Why are quantum systems fabricated to be anharmonic?

Tags: qiskit, experimental-realization

I was following the Qiskit textbook:

https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/calibrating-qubits-pulse.html

In this, there is a statement as indicated below:

> With superconducting qubits, higher energy levels are also available,
> but we fabricate the systems to be anharmonic so that we can control
> which transition we are exciting. That way, we are able to isolate two
> energy levels and treat each qubit as a basic two-level system,
> ignoring higher energy states.

I understand that there are higher energy levels available, but how are we controlling which transition we are exciting by fabricating the system to be anharmonic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Superconducting qubits are a type of quantum resonator. They are fabricated to be anharmonic so that the energy difference $\hbar \omega_{01}$ between the two lowest levels $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$ is different from the difference of any other pair of energy levels, letting us treat it as a two-level system to implement a qubit.

Specifically, we can use microwave pulses at $\omega_{01}$ to drive transitions between $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$, giving us 1-qubit operations on a two-level system. If all of the states were evenly spaced, e.g. $\omega_{01} = \omega_{12}$, then we wouldn't be able to make a two-level system/qubit because driving at that frequency would drive transitions from $|1\rangle$ to $|0\rangle$ and $|2\rangle$, and then we'd have a multi-level quantum system (which introduces all sorts of headaches theoretically and experimentally).